# subprocess.run only accepting first argument

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, command

Using Python 3.10.6
trying to pass an argument to a command line opened via subprocess.run, I've tried toggling shell=True/False, as well as passing the second argument with the input variable, no luck. here is the relevant code:

```
cmds = (['cmd','echo hello'])
cmd_result = subprocess.run(cmds, shell=False, check=True,
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            universal_newlines=True )
print(cmd_result.args)
```

> ['cmd', 'echo hello']

```
print(cmd_result.stdout)
```

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889] (c) Microsoft Corporation.
> All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\oakne\Desktop\DiscordBots>

So it seems to recognize both the arguments, its just not doing anything with the second one. Any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the command

```
cmd echo hello
```

from the CMD prompt, you do not get an echoed output of `hello`.

To run a command string, you need to add either `/C` or `/K`.  The first runs a command string and exits, the second runs a command string and stays open.  Without either of these flags, the command string is ignored.

Instead, try:

```
cmd /C echo hello
```

Adding this to your subprocess command, you get:

```py
cmds = (['cmd', '/C', 'echo', 'hello'])
cmd_result = subprocess.run(cmds, shell=False, check=True,
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            universal_newlines=True )
print(cmd_result.stdout)
# prints:
hello
```